# Remove UIButton highlight for all buttons in an app

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I'm wondering if there's a way to remove the highlight from UIButtons in my app. I know how to do it for an individual button (`adjustsImageWhenHighlighted`) but I don't want to go through all the buttons in my app and do it. Is it possible to set `adjustsImageWhenHighlighted` to `false` in the App Delegate so it applies to all buttons?

Comment: Just create the Buttons with Custom type and not with System type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
UIButton.appearance().adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false
```

Then all the default value `adjustsImageWhenHighlighted` of UIButton is `false`

Answer (score 2):

```
private let button: NoHighlightButton = NoHighlightButton()

class NoHighlightButton: UIButton {        
    override var highlighted: Bool {        
        didSet{        
            super.highlighted = false        
          }        
   }        
}
```

Comment: Could you please add some explanation along with it.